# Adding R2 value to plots

Tags: r, plot

How do I add r2 value to this plot?

```
POI<- read.csv(file="PeaksOfInterest_MassRemaining.csv", header = T)

model.1080 <- lm(POI$Mass_Remaining~POI$Wavenumber_1080, data=POI) #regression model
plot(model.1080) #plot results
summary(model.1080) #add regression line
plot(POI$Wavenumber_1080, POI$Mass_Remaining, col='red', main='Summary of Regression Model 1080', xlab='Intensities at Wavenumber 1080', ylab='Mass Remaining') #create scatterplot of raw data
abline(lm(POI$Mass_Remaining~POI$Wavenumber_1080), col="blue") #add fitted regression line
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can use `text()` and a combination of `paste()` and a similar fit from `lm()` to add it.

If you shared some data, `dput(POI)` if it isn't too large, would make it easier to help.

Comment: Not sure how to share data on here..? Sorry, new to SO.

Would I put the text() and paste() in the plot() function?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610 and a warm welcome!